# Redis / Java / Lettuce - how to access context objects

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

I'm working with Redis pub/subscribe pattern, adding a Listener for the subscriber, from a class (myClass). From the listener thread I need to access the variables/objects of the thread that is setting up the listener in order to process the messages. Is it possible? or do I need to change the approach?

This portion of code shows the Listener setup and from where I need to access myClass variables.

```
import io.lettuce.core.*;
import io.lettuce.core.api.StatefulRedisConnection;
import io.lettuce.core.pubsub.StatefulRedisPubSubConnection;
import io.lettuce.core.pubsub.RedisPubSubListener;
import io.lettuce.core.pubsub.api.sync.RedisPubSubCommands;


public class myClass implements IStrategy {
    private IEngine engine = IEngine.getEngine();
    private int tagCounter = 0;
    private double[] ma1 = new double[Instrument.values().length];
    private IConsole console;


    public void mySubscription(String channel){


        RedisClient redisClient = RedisClient.create("redis://password@<myip>:6379/0");
        StatefulRedisPubSubConnection<String, String> connection = redisClient.connectPubSub();


        connection.addListener(new RedisPubSubListener<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public void message(String channel, String message) {
                // I need to access myClass instance objects here
            }

.....
```

Disclaimer: From 1 to 10 my Java skill is 2.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Did you try to access them? Are you having any error?

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: Thanks @EdgarDomingues, you are right, it works, what I saw was that Intellij Idea was highlighting as error methods from enclosing class members, but now is working fine. Surely I was doing something wrong or had some typo I don't know. Regards